# maintain link color when clicked until clicking on another link

Tags: jquery, html, css, colors

Below each of my post on my webpage, I have 3 buttons : "Written By", "Related Post" and "In This Category": [SoCatchy!](http://socatchy.net/vfiles-watch-or-participate/)

I want to add a color when clicking on each button, and to maintain it until clicking on another link.

Here's my following code:

HTML:

```
<ul class="tabnav-widget ui-tabs-nav">
   <li class="ui-tabs-selected">
      <a class="" href="#tab1-widget">written by</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a class="" href="#tab3-widget">Related Posts</a>
   </li>
   <li class="">
      <a class="" href="#tab4-widget">In this Category</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.tabnav li a, .tabnav-widget li a{color:@white;}
.tabnav li:active, .tabnav-widget li:active{background:@white;}
```

In jQuery, I don't really know the function I have to build in order to applicate what I want.
I need help for constructing it.

I thank you in advance, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with javascript.

```
$(".tabnav-widget li a").click(function(){        
   if(!($(this).hasClass("active"))){
       $(".tabnav-widget li a.active").removeClass("active");
       $(this).addClass("active");
   }       
});
```

Comment: The `hasClass` check isn't necessary `$(".tabnav-widget li a.active").removeClass("active"); $(this).addClass("active");`

Comment: just to avoid flickering.. `.removeClass()` and `.addClass()` might result flickering.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, but it doesn't seems to work.
I want for instance a red color when clicking on one of the 3 button, and to maintain it until clicking on an other link.
Have I to modificate something in my CSS class?

Thank you for your time

Comment: yes, your `active` class must have different color than your `li a` for example `.tabnav li:active, .tabnav-widget li:active{background:@red;}`. otherwise, `active` class will not be visible.